# why is Convex function <= Concave function a valid cvx constraint?

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization, cvx

I am studying using CVX on MATLAB and encountering this problem that why is the following constraint:
Convex function <= Concave function
a valid CVX constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically because if f is concave, then -f is convex. So say we have:

```
f(x) <= g(x)      with f convex, and g concave
```

then that means

```
f(x)-g(x) <= 0    f-g is convex
```